# Upload a OS to Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-migrate-for-compute-engine

I was looking on the prices on the calculator when see on Free saying `"... or User Provided OS"`. And I want know how I upload a OS to  Google Compute Engine.

Comment: Are you inquiring about uploading a custom OS to GCP? Your post is unfortunately unclear. Would you be able to provide clarification?

Comment: `Sorry for the difficulty with the text. I'm not very good with English.`   Yes. I'm looking for upload a OS to GCP.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to import/migrate a custom instance to GCP. Two possible and popular solutions would be either migrating with [Velostrata](https://velostrata.com/support/) or using [CloudEndure](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vm-migration/using-cloud-endure).

Answer (score 0):

To upload or import a boot disk image to Compute Engine, you may use the following process:

1. Plan your import path. You must identify where you are going to prepare your boot disk image before you upload it, and how you are going to connect to that image after it boots in the Compute Engine environment.
2. Prepare your boot disk so it can boot within the Compute Engine environment and so you can access it after it boots.
3. Create and compress the boot disk image file.
4. Upload the image file to Google Cloud Storage [1] and import the image to Compute Engine as a new custom image [2].
5. Use the imported image to create a virtual machine instance and make sure it boots properly.
6. If the image does not successfully boot, you can troubleshoot the issue by attaching the boot disk image to another instance and reconfiguring it.
7. Optimize the image [3] and install the Linux Guest Environment [4] so that your imported operating system image can communicate with the metadata server and use additional Compute Engine features.

You may visit this link to learn on how to import Boot Disk Images to Compute Engine [5].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#custom_images

[3] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/configuring-imported-images

[4] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/configuring-imported-images#install_guest_environment

[5] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image